# how to set ASCII code to the button when the page loads

Tags: javascript, html

I'm designing chess board in HTML. `&#9814` is the code to display the WHITE ROOK.
I'm trying to set the value while page loads and it is displaying it as a string, but the ROOK is not coming on the button

```
function load() {
    document.getElementById('A1').value="&#9814";
}
```

Comment: You need a semicolon at the end `&#9814;`

Comment: nope,its not working.i tried it

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/RM5VD/ then your problem must be elsewhere. What are you seeing on the button? Does the function fire at all?

Comment: im gettin the string value..."&#9814" as the value...the function is firing

Comment: I see a little chess piece on that fiddle. What do you see, OP?

Comment: if u enter it with out comma also its showing the ROOK on that fiddle

Comment: What kind of element are you trying to update?

Comment: WHITE ROOK-&#9814 @codelark

Comment: No, i mean what is the html tag? eg. button, input, p, div, etc.

Comment: i want to update it on the button,when the page loads the white rook should be visible on it

Answer (score 1):

```
 function load() {
    document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML="&#9814;";
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RM5VD/2/

Answer (score 1):

The notation `&#9814` or `&#9814;` has no special meaning in JavaScript; they are just strings of characters, though these strings can be assigned to the `innerHTML` property, causing HTML parsing.

The simplest way use a Unicode character in JavaScript to insert it as such, though this requires a suitable editor and the use of the UTF-8 character encoding. Example:

```
document.getElementById('A1').value = '♖';
```

The next simplest is to use the *JavaScript* escape notation, namely `\u` followed by exactly four hexadecimal digits. Since WHITE CHESS ROOK is U+2656 (2656 hex = 9815 decimal), you would use this:

```
document.getElementById('A1').value="\u2656";
```

This makes sense only if the element modified has the `value` property as per HTML specs. For example, `<input type=button>` has it, but `button` doesn’t. But this affects just the left hand of the assignment, i.e. what you assign the string to.

Beware that [font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2656/fontsupport.htm) to chess piece characters like this is rather limited. Moreover, browsers may have their own ideas of the font to be used in buttons. In practice, you should probably use some downloadable font.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the function like this:

```
function load() {
    document.getElementById('A1').value=String.fromCharCode(9814);
}
```

It's not clear exactly what kind of element you're modifying, but you may need to modify the `innerHTML` instead of the `value` depending on your situation.

The way you have it, it is passing the text as a literal string, not a representation of a single character.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vKPJn/1/)